# How to fix broken Typescript definitions when definitions files are updated

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependencies, typescript-typings, package.json

I have a project that uses Typescript, using the newer *@types/foo* style of installing typings packages.

When my build server installs all npm modules, sometimes I get a complete failure when compiling the typescript as some dependent definitions are no longer matching up.

For instance, I now have a problem with *@types/gulp*. In **its** `package.json`, dependencies are listed as:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/node": "*",
  "@types/orchestrator": "*",
  "@types/vinyl": "*"
},
```

But now *@types/orchestrator* has updated, and it now breaks the version of *@types/gulp* that I have defined in my apps `package.json`.

How am I supposed to lock down version of dependencies like this so I no longer get this problem, or is there another workaround?

Unfortunately, I suddenly get these issues which sets development back by hours trying to sort it out. This makes using Typescript in a fast moving environment difficult.

Comment: Almost every time I clone a sample typescript project on github, it does not compile because of stuff like this.  Typescript is kind of nice, but not if stuff that used to work is always breaking.

Answer (score 0):

> How am I supposed to lock down version of dependencies like this so I no longer get this problem

Run `npm shrinkwrap` or just specify an exact version:

```
"@types/vinyl": "6.3.12"
```

Comment: As mentioned, the "*" is in the dependencies of @types/gulp, not my package.json